# primefaces selectonemenu ajax listener not working in Dialog Box

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces

I am trying to retrieve the value of Dropdown/selectonemenu, which is in Dialog.
But not getting it using listener/valueChangeListener.

My xhtml code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="test" value="#{report.location}" style="width:13% !important;">
<p:ajax listener="#{report.locationChange}" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="All" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="INSHOP" itemValue="INSHOP" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="INSTORAGE" itemValue="INSTORAGE" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

My Java code for listener to print the value for location:

```
public void locationChange() {
//location = (String) ((UIOutput) event.getSource()).getValue();
System.out.println("Location :: "+location);
}
```

Its not printing the location, just giving me NULL.

But when i am trying the same thing outside the DIALOG box, its showing the correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **valueChangeListener="#{report.locationChange}"** in p:selectOneMenu instead of p:ajax

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{qbaggageModel.deliveryAddrType}">
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue=""> </f:selectItem>
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Permanent" itemValue="Perm"> </f:selectItem>
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Temporary" itemValue="Temp"> </f:selectItem>
   <f:ajax execute="@form" render="delDtlsDiv" listener="#{qbaggageHandler.copyAddress}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**Note :** This code should be enclosed in a <h:form></h:form>

Comment: i tried that also, but still not getting the result. I guess the main issue is its inside a Dialog Box. Otherwise its working fyn.

Comment: Ideally it should work. Have you tried giving event="change" in p:ajax. Also set immediate=true and try.

Comment: No its still not working. It might be the Dialog Box issue. Coz its working outside of it.

Comment: Do you have any requirement to use primefaces. I have heard of issues regarding primefaces not working in certain browsers. If it was me, I would have gone with h:selectOneMenu and <f:ajax execute="@form">

Comment: i dont have to execute the whole form. Need to update the dialog box only.

Comment: It wont execute the entire form as a submit. It will help to bind all the form values to your backing bean. You can try execute="@this" as well.

Comment: I am trying this now, but still not getting the output <f:ajax listener="#{report.locationChange}" update="position_dialog" execute="@form"/> . Its still showing me NULL as output, not the value i am selecting from drop down.

Comment: why are you using update="position_dialog"? If you are trying to refresh that element use render="position_dialog" in f:ajax

Comment: I have pasted a code snippet in the answer section which works perfectly for me. Please read the "Note" as well.

Comment: Its working now with form tag, but now its not updating the position_dialog, this component is also in same form.

Comment: Give render=":formName:position_dialog". formName is the name given in <h:form>